# Paragraph formatting in Crystal Reports 2008

Tags: crystal-reports

I am using Crystal reports 2008, where in I have the below string:

```
My name is Jill.          I am from NY.           I live in xyz street.
```

the above string should printed as:

```
My name is Jill.       
I am from NY.           
I live in xyz street.
```

Could you please help how can I achieve this by using HTML Text Interpretation under 'Paragraph' tab.

Comment: are you using Crystal as a standalone application or using C#? Where is the `paragraph tab`?

Comment: I am not using C#, I am using it as stand alone. I am designing a RPT file where extract data from XML file. In that XML file, we have a description field which shows My name is Jill.          I am from NY.           I live in xyz street.

Comment: paragraph tab comes only when ur display string codes are commented:  right click on the field--format field--paragraph tab

Comment: I don't know about HTML but if you want to split then you can use `Split(<<String>>,".")[1]+chrw(13)+Split(<<String>>,".")[2]+chrw(13)+Split(<<String>>,".")[3]+chrw(13)`

Comment: when I use this formula, it says A number or Currency amount is required here.

Comment: can you post the formula you have used

Comment: Split({table.field},".")[1]+chrw(13)+Split({table.field},".")[2]+chrw(13)+Split({table.field},".")[3]+chrw(13)

Comment: Its working for me.. what datatype will `{table.field}` holds?